# How to prevent user from direct url entering

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 Framework.I have a directory which contains 10 PDF files i.e pdf1,pdf2....pdf10. On button click i am using Response.Redirect & passing Pdf file path in order to open it in the browser. but, this enables user to view the path(url) of the PDF folder using this url he can open any other pdf directly. How can i stop him accessing PDF directly from the url

Comment: I guess that will be difficult unless you create some kind of authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]` this will tell you where the request had come from. If its not on your site then take appropriate action.

e.g.

```
if(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"].ToLower().IndexOf("mysite.com") == -1){
    // Not from my site
    Response.Redirect("NotAllowed.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Can you please add details what you mean to say.

Comment: This won't work if the redirected url goes directly to the pdf as there is nowhere to run this code. What needs to be done is to redirect to a httphandler so that a check can then be made before streaming the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=270) may help you to stop him accessing PDF directly from the url.

Comment: Using a httphandler is the correct option if you want to perform some kind of server side check before streaming the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in Global.asax.cs and Call [NoDirectAccess] to all controllers

```
    //Prevent direct URL access: Call [NoDirectAccess] to all controllers to block
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class NoDirectAccessAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer == null ||
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host != filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Host)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                               RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", area = "" }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a secure layer.  If you are using MVC it will probably be simpler to implement since you will do the authorisation in the controller action.  However, for classic ASP you will probably need to implement a custom handler.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution to this. You could devise some sort of rolling code based on the server date/time that must be part of the query string and check for the correctness of this in the page load, if you make it sufficiently complicated / long, then people will not be able to enter this manually.